# Access referred closure value from returned function

Tags: python

I have a closure

```
def create_f():
   a = 5
   def _inner(x):
      return a * x
   return _inner
f = create_f()
```

The nested function `f` refers to the value `a` defined in the enclosing function. Is it possible to access the value of `a` just having `f`, e.g.:

```
get_deref_value_magic('a', f) # should be 5
```

I need this because I'm writing a module which disassemble functions, using [dis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html), to create OpenCL/Cuda code from it. In this scenario I stuck with the following instruction because I don't know how to access the value `a`:

> Instruction(opname='LOAD_DEREF', opcode=136, arg=0, argval='a',
>   argrepr='a', offset=0, starts_line=22, is_jump_target=False)

(How) can I access the actual value of `a` (which is `5`)?

Comment: I wouldn’t call this a higher order function. That IMHO is a function taking abother function as argument. However, the term relevant for you and your research here is a closure. This is what the surrounding captured names are called, and that might help you sea4ching here for an answer.

Comment: Having to correct terms lead me to the solution quickly, thanks @deets : `f.__closure__[0].cell_contents`